# Listen for Sendgrid Webhooks in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

I haven't used webhooks before so I wanted to understand how it works before implementing the listener with a rails app.

[SendGrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) say the webhook can notify my URL when an email is delivered.

I assume I don't want to store each notification as a new row in a database, because if we're sending millions of emails, that can quickly build up.

Should I be implementing a listener that increments a counter? For example:

```
create_table "campaign", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text  "name"
    t.integer  "delivered"
    t.integer  "failed"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end
```

Whenever a new notification is received via the webhook:

```
campaign.delivered += 1
campaign.save
```

Is a counter the correct way to handle webhooks?

Edit: I just read in the docs:

> It is possible to see duplicate events in the data posted by the Event
>   Webhook.
>
> We recommend that you use some form of deduplication when processing
>   or storing your Event Webhook data using the sg_event_id as a
>   differentiator, since this ID is unique for every event.

Does this mean I must save each event as a database row with a sg_event_id?

Comment: There''s no good reason not to store millions of records in a database, but it sounds like you don't really care about the records, so why store anything at all? Just ignore the webhook entirely if you don't care about the details.

Comment: @JimStewart For each batch of emails (ie: campaign #5), I need the percentage of mail that was delivered, bounced, failed, etc. But apparently, simply adding a counter would not work since sometimes duplicate events are sometimes sent.